# What is the best parent to use when weight painting?

Tags: weight-painting

I have a simple minecraft looking character and i'm trying to assign weights to my armatures and i was wondering the best parent to use in order to successfully weight paint on my armatures

Comment: what do you mean "the best parent"?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest, fastest method is parenting with automatic weights first and then adjusting it. It does the job fairly well, and cleaning up the weight paint should be pretty easy with your type of character.

Just make sure you apply the scale of the character mesh before applying the armature. That can definitely save some tweaking later on.